# Какой тип данных выбрать в бд?

Tags: mysql

Какой тип данных выбрать в бд mysql для числа с плавающей точкой? Но число не всегда будут с плавающей точкой, иногда оно может быть и целочисленным.

Comment: `float` .......

Comment: Вопрос в заданном виде лишён смысла. Тип данных на 90% определяется физическим смыслом хранимой информации, а на остальные 10% - типом операций, выполняемых с этими данными. Если сомневаетесь - всегда используйте точный тип данных (DECIMAL).